# Mongodb big collection size

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, server

I have a collection of size 68kb in JSON format, but when I use the db.collection.stats(), and check the "size" of my collection, it says it is nearly 3mb.

What is the reason for this, and how can I decrease the size of my collection?

Note that, I have only one document in my collection.

Comment: Run `Object.bsonsize(db.coll.findOne())` to check your document size.

Comment: Yes you are right, the bsonsize size is consistent with collection.stats(). The 64kb was the compressed version of it. Thank you.

Comment: Pay attention, after un unclean shutdown of mongodb db.collection.stats() may be inaccurate. 
Which is the scale parameter you are using? 
Remember that in db.collection.stats():
    1. size refers to logical allocation (the one seen by database engine).
    2. storageSize refers to physical file space allocation.